# SQL Query expensive when try to combine everything into one query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I'm trying to join two queries into one.

First

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VH' and plate_numbers > 9949 
ORDER BY plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..4.45 rows=1 width=70)"
  ->  Index Scan using plate_type_letters_numbers_idx on list (cost=0.43..92.86 rows=23 width=70)
```

Second

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VI'
ORDER BY plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..4.44 rows=1 width=70)"
  ->  Index Scan using plate_type_letters_numbers_idx on list (cost=0.43..16839.19 rows=4426 width=70)
```

Shouldn't the following query have a similar cost?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE (plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VH' and plate_numbers > 9949) or (plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VI')
ORDER BY plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..171.36 rows=1 width=70)
  ->  Index Scan using plate_type_letters_numbers_idx on list  (cost=0.43..760448.31 rows=4449 width=70)
```

Doing it with UNION have a very good response time, although the cost is higher. Not sure why is showing that low values in the limit.

```
SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VH' and plate_numbers > 9949
UNION
SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE (plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VI')
ORDER BY plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1
```

```
Limit  (cost=15994.01..15994.01 rows=1 width=879)
  ->  Sort  (cost=15994.01..16005.13 rows=4449 width=879)
        Sort Key: list.plate_type, list.plate_letters, list.plate_numbers
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=15927.27..15971.76 rows=4449 width=879)
              Group Key: (list of fields redacted)
              ->  Append  (cost=0.43..15704.82 rows=4449 width=879)
                    ->  Index Scan using list_plate_type_letters_numbers_idx on list  (cost=0.43..92.86 rows=23 width=70)
                          Index Cond: ((plate_type = 3) AND ((plate_letters)::text = 'VH'::text) AND (plate_numbers > 9949))
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on list list_1  (cost=133.80..15545.23 rows=4426 width=70)
                          Recheck Cond: ((plate_type = 3) AND ((plate_letters)::text = 'VI'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on list_plate_type_letters_numbers_idx  (cost=0.00..132.69 rows=4426 width=0)
                                Index Cond: ((plate_type = 3) AND ((plate_letters)::text = 'VI'::text))
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.list
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('list_id_seq'::regclass),
    plate character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    plate_type smallint,
    plate_letters character varying(4) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    plate_numbers smallint,
    CONSTRAINT list_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Index used:

```
CREATE INDEX plate_type_letters_numbers_idx
    ON public.list USING btree
    (plate_type ASC NULLS LAST, plate_letters COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, plate_numbers ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

**EDIT**

After the suggestion to use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT) here is the query that uses OR.

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..605.05 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=61290.240..61290.242 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1159648 read=288499 dirtied=31655 written=11144
  ->  Index Scan using plate_type_letters_numbers_idx on list  (cost=0.43..764232.91 rows=1264 width=71) (actual time=61290.236..61290.237 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (plate_type = 3)
        Filter: ((((plate_letters)::text = 'VH'::text) AND (plate_numbers > 9949)) OR ((plate_type = 3) AND ((plate_letters)::text = 'VI'::text)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2698980
        Buffers: shared hit=1159648 read=288499 dirtied=31655 written=11144
Planning Time: 0.301 ms
Execution Time: 61291.201 ms
```

The number of hits was extremely high.

Comment: Add create table statements including indexes to your post. For your UNION query you may want to try `(SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE plate_type = 3 and plate_letters = 'VH' and plate_numbers > 9949 ORDER BY plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1) union all (SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1) ORDER BY 
plate_type, plate_letters, plate_numbers 
LIMIT 1`

Comment: The cost value isn't typically a good way to compare queries. Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (not just a "simple" explain). OR conditions are notoriously hard to optimize (not only in Postgres) and using a UNION is very often a good alternative.

Comment: @Lennart, I've added the table and index used. Thanks for the suggestion, indeed is a way better query that I thought.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the explain mention, I would take that in consideration next time.